# Django-xmpp -Ejabberd Integration

Tags: django, xmpp, django-rest-framework, ejabberd

I have created a django-rest project so that a user can register using email and subsequently user can activate the account using email link. The  user authentication for rest server is working fine.

However, I want to create a ejabberd server for an instant messaging apps. I want to use external authentication method in ejabberd so that ejabberd can use the django project data.

Hence as per the guide line in [Django-xmpp](https://github.com/fpytloun/django-xmpp) I am trying the following.

I have change the lines in ejabberd.cfg as

```
{auth_method, external}.
{extauth_program, "/home/...../ejabberd_auth.sh"}.
```

After that I have created a file name ejabberd_auth.sh which contains the following

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/------/src #(my django-rest project folder/location of manage.py)
python manage.py ejabberd_auth $@
```

Then I changed the setting.py in my django project. The settings file looks like

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '-------'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Rest Framework app
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    # Internal Apps
    'data',
    'django_gravatar',
    'xmpp',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',

    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions'
    )
}

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ndMyFirst.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ndMyFirst.wsgi.application'
XMPP_DOMAIN = 'localhost'
XMPP_BOSH_SERVICE_URL = 'localhost:5280/http-bind'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
```

Then I started ejabberd server. When I am trying to login in *127.0.0.1:5280/admin* **unauthorized response received**. I have also tried to register a user using *ejabberdctl register admin localhost password* and **not allowed** message received. 
I do not have any idea the external authentication works. 
What should I do so that the external authentication works.

Comment: **Unauthorized response received** means your external authentication scripts fails at some point while authentication. You need to check that. If it works then you can even register the user and **not allowed** message will not be raised more.

Comment: Where you able to integrate DRF with XMPP? If so, how?

Comment: I could not able to integrate using Django-xmpp. However, I am using http authentication module in ejabberd (ejabberd_auth_http), so that it can request the server to check if the user registered.